# Unity PlayerPrefs only save 1 item to all

Tags: unity-game-engine, save

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ItemScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Click click;
public Text MPSInfo;
public ItemManager[] items;

void Start()
{
    LoadItems();
    StartCoroutine(AutoTick());
}

void Update()
{
    MPSInfo.text = "Money/Sec: " + MoneyPerSec();
}

public int MoneyPerSec()
{
    int tick = 0;
    foreach(ItemManager item in items)
    {
        tick += item.count * item.tickValue;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(item.ItemName + "Count", item.count);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(item.ItemName + "Cost", item.cost);
        print(item.ItemName);
        print(item.count);
        print(item.cost);
    }
    return tick;
}

public void AutoMoneyPerSec()
{
    Click.money += MoneyPerSec();
}

IEnumerator AutoTick()
{
    while(true)
    {
        AutoMoneyPerSec();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}

public void LoadItems()
{
    foreach(ItemManager item in items)
    {
        item.count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(item.ItemName + "Count");
        item.cost = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(item.ItemName + "Cost");
        print(item.ItemName);
        print(item.count);
        print(item.cost);
    }
}
```

}

I have this script, and i have 2 items set up, for testing, but Playerprefs only saves the second item for the second and for the first item. They are the same cost, and count..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you put in as `items` from your editor?

Are they references of the same `GameObject`?

Comment: Just used 'PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()' and now both of them's cost is 0.

Comment: The Itemscript is on my MPSInfo text, thats where i put my items.

Comment: @Kalip All looks ok to me here. How do you *put* the items in this script from outside?

Comment: @Kalip Now, the only possible reason I could think of is that the `itemManager` script might have `count` and `cost` as static variables. Make sure they are not. Also, try this using some more number of items, and/or assign some default values to each item's `count` and `cost`, and try to `print()` them before assigning them within the `foreach` loop

Comment: Cost and count is not static

Comment: And everything is fine, but this only happe

Comment: Its only happens when playerprefs is loaded

Comment: If i use 3 items instead of 2 then the item 3. will be saved to all items.

Comment: @Kalip Within the `foreach` loops of both `MoneyPerSec()` and `LoadItems()`, `print()` the `item.itemName`, `item.cost`, and `item.count`, and ensure correct values are being printed

Comment: No keep it just the way it is, just put the `print()` statements, and check your logs

Comment: It prints out this: Item Name , 0, 1000 ; 0 is the count number, and 1000 is the cost, updated above with the print statements.

Comment: 1000 is the cost of item 3.

Comment: Finally i have solved it, the problem was that i had a UI Text ItemName, and a string itemName, and the I was capital letter.... Thanks for help. :)

Comment: @Kalip Glad to hear that